# Why won't my program terminate?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, process, windows-ce, termination

I have a .NET Compact Framework app that can runs on three windows machines (Desktop windows and two WinCE machines) and on the WinCE devices, the process never terminates on exit, even if I call Application.Exit(). Besides .NET, it uses one COM component (which does everything on the UI thread). If I break into the debugger after exitting, Visual Studio shows only one thread and a completely blank call stack.

What could possibly cause this?

Update: My process is terminating on the desktop but not the WinCE machines. I tried to force the process to terminate with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint uExitCode);

static public void ExitProcess()
{
    if (Platform.IsWindowsCE)
        TerminateProcess(new IntPtr(-1), 0);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

There are also supposed to be ExitProcess() and GetCurrentProcess() APIs like the following, but if I try to call them, I get EntryPointNotFoundException. Therefore I am using TerminateProcess(-1, 0) because the documentation for the desktop version of GetCurrentProcess claims that it simply returns -1.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int ExitProcess(IntPtr hProcess);
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
```

Even throwing an unhandled exception won't do it.

Update 2: the simplest program that causes the problem merely creates the COM object.

```
static void Main()
{
    new FastNavLib.MapControl();
}
```

C++ programs that use the COM component do not exhibit this behavior, so my C++ COM component must have some bizarre interaction with the .NET framework which I will investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort-of figured it out.

My COM object sets itself up to get `WM_TIMER` messages through a hidden window. Basically:

```
// Register window class
WNDCLASS wc;
memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
wc.lpfnWndProc = &WinCeTimerProc;
wc.lpszClassName = _T("FastNavTimerDummyWindow");
// Create window
gTimerWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, wc.lpszClassName, 
    WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
gTimerID = SetTimer(gTimerWindow, 88, gTimerIntervalMs, NULL);
```

(Experts might point out I don't need a timer window to receive timer messages--the last parameter of `SetTimer` can be set to a callback function. Indeed, if I use a callback instead of a timer window, the problem disappears! However, I had to use a timer window to work around a strange bug in WinCE in which `SetTimer(NULL,...)` can cause `WM_TIMER` messages to received by somebody that calls `PeekMessage()`.)

Now, when the last COM object that uses the timer is destroyed, the timer and timer window are also destroyed:

```
KillTimer(gTimerWindow, gTimerID);
DestroyWindow(gTimerWindow);
```

Unfortunately, `DestroyWindow()` never returns. I assume there is some kind of deadlock in `DestroyWindow`, though it is not clear why the call stack is blank when I pause in Visual Studio. Perhaps because the COM object is destroyed automatically instead of by `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, it is destroyed in the finalizer thread, and `DestroyWindow` cannot be called from the finalizer thread on WinCE. As usual Microsoft doesn't spell out the danger in its documentation, stating only "Do not use DestroyWindow in one thread to destroy a window created by a different thread."

The solution was simple: don't destroy the timer window at all, as the OS destroys it automatically when the process exits.

Fun fact: the problem with `DestroyWindow` does not occur if I call `SetTimer(NULL,...)` instead of `SetTimer(gTimerWindow,...)`, but it **does** occur if I don't call `SetTimer` at all.

Answer (score 3):

look like you have some threads still running in your application.

Make sure you have terminate every child thread before exiting the main one.

Comment: Like I mentioned, mine is a single-threaded application. I wrote all the code in the app, including the COM component, so I should know. Since the process terminates successfully on the desktop, perhaps there is some difference between the "rules of process termination" on WinXP and WinCE?

Comment: no, there are no different rules.  The COM component is creating a thread and that thread is not getting terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch - make sure `CoUninitialize()` is called before exit?
Also, instead of breaking into a debugger create a crash dump and debug that. Not sure how this works on CE, but that's what'd I'd recommend on Windows.

Comment: Maybe that's something to try when my C++ apps don't terminate (which happens irritatingly often), but .NET apps shouldn't have to call that.

Comment: How do you make a crash dump and debug it, and why would that be better than using the VS debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If an app doesn't exit that usually means that there's one handle still open which can't be closed from userspace. And that means there's a buggy driver.

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx) about details.

Comment: The only special device used by the app is a COM port, and the process doesn't terminate even if I don't open the COM port.

Comment: Oh wait, I also play sounds with waveOutOpen etc. I suppose I could look into that as a cause.

Comment: Nope, commenting out the waveOutOpen call doesn't help.

Comment: based on his post it's unlikely a driver issue.  It's a thread issue, and it's not at all uncommon in the CF.

Answer (score 1):

Your COM object is creating a thread in the background and that thread is not terminating.  It's likely that this is because the COM object is not getting released in your code.

Try calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject before exiting, so your simple test app would look like this:

```
static void Main() 
{ 
    // create the COM object
    var obj = new FastNavLib.MapControl(); 

    // simulate doing stuff
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // release the COM object
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: My COM object does not create any threads. I have also confirmed that the COM object is released normally, using OutputDebugString at the end of the ATL method FinalRelease(). I have now learned that the problem is somehow caused by creating a window to receive WM_TIMER messages, so I'll post an answer about that.